# How to use system font settings for a Windows C# app

Tags: c#, winforms

For a windows application (C#), is it possible to adjust the entire application (including all forms) to use system font settings for size rather than using fixed sizes?

This is for users with visual impairment who have set a bigger font size on their machines. Is it possible for the application to adjust the font according to what the user has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructors of your forms (before calling `InitializeComponent()`), I would try setting the Font property of your forms equal to `System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont`.  If your controls (ex: textboxes) don't specify a specific font then I believe they inherit their font properties from their parent containers (i.e. forms).

There are other more specific system fonts (like the default setting for the Caption's font) in the [System.Drawing.SystemFonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.aspx) class.  You may want to investigate those further as well.

Comment: `SystemFonts.DefaultFont` works fine, but i would not recommend it to be called before form initialization. It causes distorted control drawings. It worked for me when I employed it under form load..

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `AutoScaleMode` property of all your forms to the value `AutoScaleMode.Font` if you want your application to be scaled by system font, or `AutoScaleMode.Dpi` if you want it to be scaled by windows DPI settings.

Here you can find some more info - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the code and found that the AutoScaleMode property for all forms is already set to AutoScale.Font. For testing, I change the font size on my machine to Extra Large and found that only the titlebar of my application scales to reflect this change. Everything else on the form (panels, buttons, text etc) is still the same size. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: You should probably set the value of this property to AutoScaleMode.Dpi. In Windows 7 display settings there is even option that says "Set custom text size (DPI)". I pressume it's the same in older windows but they don't make it clear enough that DPI is responsible for larger size of the same value fonts. You can look at it this way - if you set the font size to 12, that same size on higher DPI (for example 125%) is higher (15). By setting AutoScaleMode to Font, your program on higher DPI screen will be scaled down so that it seems like 12. If it's DPI, it will remain 12 (or 15 in higher DPI).

Comment: Thanks for the help Ivan. The application now handles the font scaling very well.

However, to make it accessibility complaint I need to make it work if the user sets the High Contrast settings. Right now if I set the High Contrast Settings (Control Panel - Accessibility - Display) most of the text on the form disappears and the UI looks ugly. Is there a way we can reflect the High Contrast changes in our application?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: There are not out-of-the-box solutions for this problem. But it can be handled by using AccessibilityObject property of the form. For more info look at the example in the MSDN documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get dpi width
float x = this.CreateGraphics().DpiX;

// if screen is width
if (x == 120)
    // Get big image from Resources
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.BigImage;

else if (x==96)
{
    // Get small image from Resources
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.loading49;

    this.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E6E6E6");
    this.button2.Size = new Size(85, 30);
    this.button1.Size = new Size(75, 24);
    this.textBox1.Size = new Size(150, 40);
}
```