# RichTextBox Scroll bars not showing on some PCs

Tags: c#, richtextbox, scrollbars

I am showing a form which i have a TabControl, and in the tabcontrol i have coded to add a  richtextbox. The text shows fine and the scroll bars all work fine on my XP PC.
When i run the program on Windows Server 2003 the text is displayed fine but no Scroll bars show.

I have set WordWrap = false and Multiline = True, and RichTextScrollbars = ForcedBoth.

What could be causing this and is there a way to resolve this ?

thanks All

Comment: Do the scrollbars show up when you write text beyond the visible boundaries of the control?

Comment: Only on my XP PC. Not on the Windows server. I thought it might be something with .NET version. so i created a 3.5 version and still the same issue.

Comment: Found the problem. Looks like the font on the server machine was larger than what was on my PC. As a result the scroll bar was too far over not too show. So i had to reduce the size of the richtextbox. Is there anyway of automating this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment regarding different font sizes, it looks like you are dealing with an accessibility issue.

From http://www.44342.com/csharp-f73-t32102-p1.htm:

> You can override the WndProc method and listen to the message stream
>   directly or simply register the form's SystemColorsChanged event.It's
>   fired whenever a user changes a display property. The documentation is
>   a little lacking on this event, but it handles colors, fonts,
>   resolutions, etc.

This may also work: [How to use system font settings for a Windows C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901299/how-to-use-system-font-settings-for-a-windows-c-sharp-app)

Comment: The user hasn't changed the font. I think they just have a different default font type which has overridden what i have defined