# Windows Forms C# application - Set font size of form controls to fit the screen when a user choose 125% or 150% for the OS font size?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, font-size, screen-resolution

We had designed a Windows Form application such that it is suitable for all the resolutions. We came across a situation where the font size of all the controls in the form has increased when the user chooses 125% or 150% for the font size. I have set the screen resolution to 1440x900 and changed the setting to 125% as shown in screenshot below

[image]

After making these settings to the machine and running the application, we found that the font size of all the controls in the form has increased and it is getting overlapped with the other controls.

Can you please suggest any code/process for detecting the increase in OS font size i.e above 100% and handle the size of the fonts for the controls?

Comment: Take a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901299/how-to-use-system-font-settings-for-a-windows-c-sharp-app This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Felixus All the forms in my windows application is using AutoScaleMode.Font. Should i change it to AutoScaleMode.Dpi?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try using

```
System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont
```

for all form elements. AutoScale.Dpi may cause some weird changes to your UI when using different monitors, scales and resolutions.

Comment: The setting System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont is getting applied correctly for the label controls but there are also WPF controls present in the form for which the setting is not getting applied. Can you please suggest on what needs to be done?

Comment: Try to apply the font family of a label that displays the correct font-size to the wpf elements. This should work. As I do not work with wpf I can't give you any further advise.

Comment: Can you please suggest on how to detect that the size of text is increased to 125% at run time in code?

Comment: If the system font property is raised after an event you can use an event handler. If not, get a second thread or BackgroundWorker to check for the systemfonts.default value. If it changes, you can raise a custom event (but this method is quite bad as it uses a relatively huge amount of ram).

Comment: When i increase the DPI scaling from 100% to 125% or 150% , the font size of the label is not getting increased. The font size for the label is same in all the DPI scaling. Still, the some of the forms are incorrectly sized such that one control is getting overlapped with the other control